# Why has this function no effect when called?

Tags: c, function

I'm a newcomer C learner and following code is my problem:

I wrote it to change the value of the passed variable, but in the output notihng has happened.

Here is my code:

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>

void change(int i, int j) {
    i = i + j;
}

int main() {
    int a = 50;

    printf("a before = %d\n", a);

    change(a, 10);

    printf("a after = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: OMG. You need a basic C lesson, don't mind.

Comment: An especially long lesson on pointers.

Comment: Look up for pass-by-value and then read about pointers.

Comment: @Arc676 beat me by 3 seconds... :)

Comment: You're not passing the variable `a`, you're passing its value. (What would you expect to happen if you did `change(10,a)`? Would ten become sixty?)

Comment: @molbdnilo that could be a funny behavior :)

Comment: For those bashing this question - it's a totally legitimate newbie question. You could have answered it properly with no loss of fidelity in the same or fewer characters than your comments consisted of.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I would not even think about using pointers here - or confuse OP even more with them. Why not just return the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple case in C.

In C, It uses a method called Call-By-Value to evaluate function parameters.
It means when you called a function with your arguments the called function receives the values of those arguments not the arguments.

Which in this program, function "change" receives integer 50 (value the 'a' is holding) and 10 instead of a and 10. So i is 50 and j is 10 when you called the function. In the function i is changed to 60. But a remains the same. If you add a printf() to print the value of i in "change" you can see the change happened.

So to make "change" effective you have to use pointers, a special "tool" in C.

you have to change your "change" function as following:

```
void change(int *pi, int *pj)
{
    *pi += *pj;
}
```

and you should change the call also.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 50, b = 10;
    /* printf line */
    change(&a, &b);
    /* printf line */
}
```

in the function "change"

> ```
>    void change(int i, int j)
> ```
>
> is changed into
>
> ```
>    void change(int *pi, int *pj)
> ```

this means that pi, pj are pointers to `int`. `pi` & `pj` are variables to hold an address of a variable.

`*pi` & `*pj` are the variable that resides in the addresses that `pi` & `pj` have.
Which means that `*pi` refers to (points to) `a`, `*pj` points to `b`

> ```
>    *pi += *pj
> ```
>
> is equal to
>
> ```
>    a = a + b;
> ```

and you can see that I have changed way "change" called

it is now

> ```
>    change(&a, &b);
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
>    change(a, 10);
> ```

the ampersand (&) gives the address of a variable
So &a and &b are the addresses of a & b, Which are meant to be hold in pi and pj

I think this lengthy answer would help you. However you should read some lessons about pointers.

Comment: Why would one pass the second argument by pointer? And why not just return the result from the function? Also you are using quite uncommon phrases (e.g. a pointer is not a "tool"). Well meant perhaps to try help a beginner, but not well done, beacuse he has to learn the terms anyway, or will become even more confused.

Answer (score 4):

Function parameters are its local variables. Function parameters are initialized by **copies** of the values of the supplied arguments. So any changing of a parameter does not influence on the corresponding argument.
After exiting the function its parameters (local variables) are destroyed.

For example you can imagine your function

```
void change(int i, int j) {
    i = i + j;
}
```

that is called like

```
change(a, 10);
```

the following way

```
void change(/*int i, int j*/) {
    int i = a;
    int j = 10;

    i = i + j;
}
```

As you can see variable a itself will not be changed.

There are two approaches. Either the first parameter will be passed by reference or the function will return its result. For example

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>

void change( int *i, int j) {
    *i = *i + j;
}

int main() {
    int a = 50;

    printf("a before = %d\n", a);

    change( &a, 10);

    printf("a after = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>

int change(int i, int j) {
    i = i + j;

    return i;
}

int main() {
    int a = 50;

    printf("a before = %d\n", a);

    a = change(a, 10);

    printf("a after = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` and `j` in `change()` are copies from the variables inside `main()`. You have to learn about pointers to achieve what you are trying to do. Basically it look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int *i, int j) {
    *i = *i + j;
}

int main() {
    int a = 50;

    printf("a before = %d\n", a);

    change(&a, 10);

    printf("a after = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```